# Como portar um servidor Web em Javascript para um executável em Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sou novo em Node.js, e desenvolvi um servidor usando o express para enviar arquivos entre computadores da mesma rede, porém só consigo iniciar o servidor no computador que irá receber o arquivo se o mesmo possuir o Node instalado. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de iniciar o servidor sem a necessidade de ter o node instalado, para plataforma Windows.

Comment: Correr o node sem ter o node instalado é como correr o windows sem o instalar. Não sei se percebi bem a pergunta... podes dar um exemplo prático ou explicar melhor?

Comment: Seria basicamente criar um executável para windows, partindo dessa aplicação. Destinado ao usuário final

Comment: Acho que o problema foi a escolha da plataforma, no caso. Se a intenção era fazer um servidor executável, provavelmente uma linguagem compilada mais completa seria melhor do que um runtime JS. Não que seja impossível, provavelmente alguém vai fazer algo do tipo (assim como o electron usa um node.js embedded). De qq forma, acaba nivelando por baixo tecnologicamente. Mas se for só por experiência e aprendizado, é legal.

Comment: Sim, a ideia é justamente o aprendizado :)

Answer (score 1):

Para criar aplicações desktop em node existe duas ferramentas muito utilizadas atualmente: http://electron.atom.io e o https://nwjs.io/

O Electron por exemplo foi utilizado para criação do editor atom, slack, visual studio code...

O único problema no seu caso é que vc já deveria ter começado a desenvolver com um desses dois desde o início. Portar o seu código que vai dar mais trabalho.

Comment: Olá Filipe, Obrigado pela resposta, irei dar uma pesquisada sobre essas duas ferramentas, Muito Obrigado!